# Как выполнить запросы через определенный интервал между ними в Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

```
function checkPrice(url_item){

    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'+url_item ;
    request(url, function(err, res, body){
            if(err){console.log(err)}
            else{ 
                console.log("body: "+body);
            }
        }
    )

}

var mas = new Array("1011935134_188530139", "991959905_0", "360454763_188530139", "1011934384_188530139", "310776726_0", "926978479_0");

mas.forEach(function() {setTimeout(checkPrice, 1000);});
```

Пишу парсер.

Удаленный сервер «отваливается» при 3-4 запросах в секунду.

Как задать интервал между запросами?

```
[2015-08-10 00:06:42.237] [DEBUG] server - req: /1011935134_188530139
[2015-08-10 00:06:42.238] [DEBUG] server - req: /991959905_0
[2015-08-10 00:06:42.239] [DEBUG] server - req: /360454763_188530139
[2015-08-10 00:06:42.239] [DEBUG] server - req: /926978479_0
[2015-08-10 00:06:42.240] [DEBUG] server - req: /1011934384_188530139
[2015-08-10 00:06:42.240] [DEBUG] server - req: /310776726_0
```

Как видно из лога, `setTimeout` результата не принесла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял задачу, вы хотите выполнить несколько запросов к удаленному серверу из программы на node.js, сделав при этом паузу между запросами.

Ваш вариант не работает, потому что `forEach` сначала последовательно "заряжает" 5 `setTimeout`'ов, потом через 1 секунду они все срабатываются и генерят 5 практически одновременных запросов к серверу.

Чтобы починить вариант с setTimeout, вам нужно "вложить" их друг в друга, например:

```
var mas = new Array("1011935134_188530139", "991959905_0", "360454763_188530139", "1011934384_188530139", "310776726_0", "926978479_0");
(function fireRequestAndWait(i) {
  checkPrice(mas[i]);
  if(i >= mas.length) return;

  setTimeout(function() {
    fireRequestAndWait(i+1);
  }, 1000);
})(0);
```

Пример только для понимания, писать я бы так не рекомендовал.

Более промышленное решение (с учетом того, что вам наверное еще и результаты запросов интересны) - найти подходящую библиотеку, которая скроет эти некрасивости за нормальным API. Как пример (не зная вашей конкретной задачи), [async#reduce](https://github.com/caolan/async#reduce).

В светлом будущем ES6 (или сейчас, если вы смело используете [io.js](https://iojs.org/en/index.html)) вы можете писать почти обычный последовательный код с помощью "генераторов" (пример утащил [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30575612/1026), `co` - еще одна [библиотека](https://github.com/tj/co)):

```
function* waitAndDo(times) {
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++) {

    // Sleep
    yield function(callback) {
      setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    }    

    // Do something here
    console.log('Doing a request');
  }
}

var co = require('co');

co(function* () {
  yield waitAndDo(10);
});
```

Comment: Очень благодарен за ответ. То что нужно)